# How to add new "Reset Actions" for emails in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

There are a certian set of reset actions provided by keycloak for email.
They are:

- Configure_TOTP
- UPDATE_PASSWORD
- UPDATE_PROFILE
- VERIFY_EMAIL

[image]

How I add a new action here along with its own email theme and its own custom inputs?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement your own [Required Action](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#required-action-walkthrough). Whole process is described in docs.